# Is there an equivalent of log.IsDebugEnabled in Winston?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

Is there an equivalent of `log.IsDebugEnabled` in Winston?

I want to use this to skip expensive logging code in a production environment but have it execute in development.

For example:

```
if(winston.isDebugEnabled){
   // Call to expensive dump routine here
   dump();
}
```

Checking `winston.debug` just checks whether the method is defined, not whether it is enabled.

Many thanks!

---

Edit: Added code example.

Answer (score 2):

I've added a method to my logger to achieve just that:

```
logger.isLevelEnabled = function(level) {
  return _.any(this.transports, function(transport) {
    return (transport.level && this.levels[transport.level] <= this.levels[level])
      || (!transport.level && this.levels[this.level] <= this.levels[level]);
  }, this);
};
```

This goes through each of your logger's transports and checks whether it 'wants' to log the specified level.
Note [_.any](http://lodash.com/docs#some) is [lodash](http://lodash.com), you can replace with for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since Winston 3.1.0 ([PR](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/pull/1352)), you can use the `Logger` functions `isLevelEnabled(string)` & `isXXXEnabled()` for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'd be able to get that directly from winston, but if you want to have different logging levels for different environments, you should pass these in when you're creating the winston.logger.

For example:

```
// default log file level is info (which is the lowest by default)
var logFileLevel = 'info';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
    // only write logs with a level of 'error' or above when in production
    logFileLevel = 'error';
}

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File)({ 
            filename: '/var/log/node-logger.log',
            level: logFileLevel
        })
    ]
});
```

It's also useful to switch out the transports. You might want to use the Console transport whilst in development, and the File transport when in production for example.

More documentation on all this on the [winston readme](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#working-with-transports).

Comment: Thanks Ben. Might have to do it this way if it isn't possible to get it out of Winston itself. I'm not sure it's a good solution for Node.js modules - the flag would have to be passed it or require a module with it in.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
if ( logger.levels[logger.level] >= logger.levels['debug'] ) {
    // expensive calculation here
    logger.debug(...)
}
```